# AS3 Drag and drop on Dell Inspiron One Touch Screen

Tags: actionscript-3

On a Dell Inspiron One TouchScreen All-in-one computer, I'm trying to use startTouchDrag() but it is not working. The monitor sends TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN and TouchEVENT.TOUCH_END but no TOUCH_MOVE when I drag my finger. My event handlers are running correctly when I touch and let go but the Sprite is not dragging. Any ideas what could be missing?

### Backstory

I have an AIR application which ran fine on an ELO touch screen. The user would drag certain items and place them into a bucket. The application listened for MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, upon which it would start startDragDrop(). On MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP it would do stopDragDrop(). On the Dell, it didn't work because when you touch the screen, it fires a simultaneous MOUSE_DOWN then MOUSE_UP event... which respectively runs startDragDrop then stopDragDrop immediately killing the drag and drop functionality. Only the TouchEvents fire correctly upon touching and letting go.

Comment: what about _MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE_ on Dell, is it fired between touch begin and end events?

Comment: With my finger, it fires one single MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE as soon as I touch and that's it. No more. Even if I move my finger around. However, if I do it with the actual mouse it works appropriately and keeps firing MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE every time I move the mouse.

Comment: So you can make some workaround and dispatch touch events manually by enter frame using _mouseX_ and _mouseY_ properties of the stage.

Comment: I tried this method but I only get the mouseX and mouseY on touch begin, and when I let go. Not as I'm dragging, which would make it impossible to craft my own custom dragdrop function.

Comment: Update. Problem solved. Downgraded to Air 3.7 and everything worked perfectly. With all original Mouse listeners, no touch listeners at all. This thread led me in the downgrade direction: http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10972

Comment: So, you can add your own answer to this question and accept it, so every one with the same problem will be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip fsbmain. I'll do that now. I hope this can help someone else out too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. Problem solved. Downgraded to Air 3.7 and everything worked perfectly. With all original Mouse listeners, no touch listeners at all. This thread led me in the downgrade direction: flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10972